# Delphi 2007 : How to Set TSAWARE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, terminal-services

In Delphi 2009 and up you can add this line to your project .dpr to set the TSAWARE PE flag in your application executable:

```
{$SetPEOptFlags  IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE}
```

I thought (wrongly) that this syntax is not supported in Delphi 2007. I have an application that I cannot port from 2007 to a newer Delphi version just yet (the task is underway, but it will not be done in the next few months).

**Update** it was simply that Windows must be added to the project .dpr also.

Comment: The syntax is supported in D2007, and the constant declaration is defined in `Windows.pas` at around line 1832 or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you are missing the `Windows` unit from your .dpr file's uses clause. Add that and you will be able to write:

```
{$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE}
```

in your .dpr file. Although clearly you need to write it after the uses clause.

The `$SetPEOptFlags` feature was added a few versions before Delphi 2007. And so the error that you are presumably seeing is simply that `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE` is not declared. And that is solved by making sure that the symbol is visible in the .dpr file. Clearly you can do that by declaring a constant in the .dpr file, but to avoid duplication I always prefer to add the Windows unit.

Answer (score 3):

compiles under D7

```
const

IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE = $8000;

{$SetPEOptFlags  IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE}
```