# Recommended PE header settings for Delphi 7 application running on terminal server?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, terminal-services

While investigating external exception C0000006 errors reported by some users running a Delphi 7 application on a Windows 2008 terminal server, I found several questions on this and related issues already.  I'm wondering if anyone has a definitive list of these settings that would be appropriate for a standard Delphi 7 database application running on a terminal server.

The questions I've looked at include:

- [External exception C0000006](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317886/)
- [Delphi - invalid stream format errors on run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766310/)
- [Are there risks associated with IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP or IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953739/)
- [Delphi TOpenDialog hangs in windows 2008 when run as remote desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206010/)
- [Delphi 2007 : How to Set TSAWARE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458485/)
- [How can I force Delphi 7 to load the whole executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414509/)

So far from reading these I'm thinking I should add the following to the .dpr file:

```
const
  IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE = $8000;
  // Following are already defined in D7's Windows.pas
  IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED               = $0001;
  IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP       = $0400;
  IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP             = $0800;

{$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE}

{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED 
  or IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP 
  or IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP}
```

**Edit:** Stripping the relocation section is probably unnecessary, so here's the revised version:

```
const
  IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE = $8000;
  // Following are already defined in D7's Windows.pas
  IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP       = $0400;
  IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP             = $0800;

{$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE}

{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP 
  or IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP}
```

Comment: The main one is the TSAWARE flag.  I'm not sure why you want IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED - Are you combining that with stripreloc because you want to make the EXE smaller? Why would that be specific to Terminal Server?

Comment: @Warren: Good point, it's not specific to terminal services but yes reducing the EXE size seemed like a good thing to me.  Is there any reason NOT to strip the relocation section?

Comment: You inhibit windows from relocating the executable, which, on an NT operating system is less of a problem than on the ancient Win95/98 systems.  I mostly think of it as a "thing you should only do if you HAVE to". For installers, it makes sense. For a regular app, it's just one more thing that could be part of a chain of badness.   In the era of terabyte hard drives, I find it odd that anyone cares if an EXE is 2 megs larger, if the cure involves running a closed source tool that modifies what my linker built. Who do ya trust, in other words.

Comment: According to [Jordan Russell](http://www.jrsoftware.org/striprlc.php) the relocation section "is actually not necessary since EXEs never get relocated."
But I accept your point, leaving the relocation section in is unlikely to cause any problems.

Comment: You are safe to strip relocation table for an exe

Comment: Just for completeness, David's statement is correct even for Windows 9x. The reason is that the EXE is always the first module to be loaded into a new process' memory space by the loader, except for a couple of shared, pre-loaded OS modules, like kernel32.dll, which are always loaded at a high address. This means that the default load address of 0x400000 is always available, so there is never any reason for the OS to have to relocate the EXE image.

Comment: Just a keyword: ASLR

Comment: @chksr: yes, but ASLR wasn't supported in versions of Delphi before Delphi 2007, AFAIK.  

https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/delphi-2007-supports-aslr-and-nx-33777

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
{$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_ SERVER_AWARE}
{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED   
  or IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP   
  or IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP}
```

is fine for your needs. I suspect that IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP is what you need to deal with C0000006. That error typically happens when you run from a network drive and the drive is not able to satisfy a page in request for the executable.

The other PE flags are fine for you either way. I would have it as you do.

As for whether or not IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_ SERVER_AWARE is right, only you know. Does you app meet the requiresments to be considered a non-legacy app for terminal services, as [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01cfys9z.aspx)? If so, use IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_ SERVER_AWARE.

Comment: Thanks David, and good point about the /TSAWARE setting.

I haven't had any reports of the C0000006 errors since introducing these settings.